# What is the metal thing on Picard's head in Violations?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *TNG* 'Violations' (S5 E12) Doctor Crusher is forced to relive the experience of Picard revealing her dead husband to her.

While they are walking down the corridor you can see a metal device attached to Picard's temple.

[image: Picard wearing a metal thing on his head]

What is this device and what does it do?

Comment: No canon information, but it is plausible that Picard was on the same away mission as Jack and suffered some injury, so this is some medical device (StarFleet band-aid, monitor, something more advanced).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a futuristic bandage.  This is from the [script for the episode](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/212.txt), with bolding mine:

> 71 CONTINUED:
>
> Martin EXITS and Beverly keeps working, engrossed in the monitor.
>
> SUBLIMINAL CUT TO:
>
> 72 INT. STARBASE MORGUE (FLASHBACK)
>
> **Picard's face and head sports a bandage.**
>
> 73 RESUME BEVERLY - PRESENT
>
> jarred by the remembrance, trying to concentrate on work once more.
>
> SUBLIMINAL CUT TO:
>
> 74 INT. STARBASE MORGUE (FLASHBACK)
>
> A body on a bio-bed, covered by a sheet (or 24th- century equivalent).
>
> PICARD'S VOICE You shouldn't remember him like this.
>
> 75 RESUME BEVERLY (PRESENT)
>
> sitting upright in her chair, frozen with shock as the overwhelming
>   memory sweeps over her.
>
> CUT TO:
>
> 76 INT. STARBASE MORGUE - MEMORY FLASHBACK
>
> (With characteristic visual treatment.)
>
> A younger Beverly -- with a different hairstyle -- and a younger
>   Picard, she in civvies and he in "Stargazer" uniform. **His head sports
>   a bandage.** The two walk toward a body on a gurney, covered by a drape.
>
> PICARD You don't have to do this...

Comment: Space bandage! Of... course.